# Apache 2 default document root won't change (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I want to prevent direct access to the server web root showing the Ubuntu home page at `/var/www/html/index.html`

I have changed the following:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/websites
```

And restarted Apache but it's still going to `/var/www/html` if I visit my server directly.

**Edit:**

It appears this problem is only when I access the server on HTTPS. On HTTP it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to change in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Find this:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change to your desired directory

Comment: I have done that as well. The problem appears to be on HTTPS actually. On HTTP it works, but on HTTPS it still goes to `/var/www/html`

Comment: in your 000-default.conf you need to duplicate the `<VirtualHost ...>` block. make sure the first one matches your desired host with the :80 port appended. ex: `<VirtualHost example.com:80>` and the second one has port 443 instead of 80